# UWP Add pane in my pivot view

Tags: uwp-xaml

I start with UWP development and I try to reproduce something I saw on one business app.
My business app model manage expense

[image]

Under the blank rectangle I have a listview with my expense.
I have I thinks a Pivot for "Expense reports" and "Unreconcilied"

But if I click on "New Expense report" I have a new pane

[image]

What is this pane in my visual toolbox ? And Where I must adding this pane in my XAML ? Before my pivot balise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pane is the [SettingsPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane) witch isn't a standard control or style and it shows a [SettingsFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout).

Windows 8.1 has a [SettingsFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout) which has built-in functionality to embed in a [SettingsPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane). But since Windows 10, there doesn't have the SettingsPane. Instead of using a [SettingsPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane), integrate settings options into the app experience is recommended in UWP. For more info, see [Guidelines for app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/guidelines-for-app-settings).

For more information and detailed steps using SettingsPane, see Quickstart: [Add app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/apps/hh872190(v=win.10)), [Quickstart: Add app help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/apps/jj649425(v=win.10)) and the [App settings sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-settings-sample-1f762f49).